# Getting linear sequence of numbers for use in Excel cell formula

Tags: excel

I often need a linear sequence of numbers for use in Excel formulas. This could be a simple sequence like 0, 1, 2 ... or 10, 20, 30 ...

What I usually do is to create a new column with the required sequence, and use its values in formulas in nearby cells. I then graph the result if I have to. In the end I just hide the extra column that was created to prevent clutter. This way its values exist but they are not visible.

Is there a better way to do this where I do not have to create a column which I need hide anyway?

Comment: The answer is in the title: [`SEQUENCE()`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/sequence-function-57467a98-57e0-4817-9f14-2eb78519ca90)

Comment: I have, in the past hidden data under the chart :) makes things look cleaner. Also, I have formatted the numbers or text in a cell the same color as the background... Or one can use the row() function and create thre desired numbers from that with a bit of maths as needed.

Comment: You can manually add a series.  It doesn't have to be a reference.  From your chart, Select Data, and either add or edit entries.  It will look like this.  ={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9}